# Motorola 6809 Prime finder

Tags: performance, primes, assembly

I'm trying to make a small program which takes a number (form 1 to 1000) and shows the primes between 2 and that number. Right now I have a quite functioning program (except a couple of bugs), but the problem is that it needs a lot of cycles. In the worst case scenario (limit = 1000) it takes roughly 2 million cycles to complete.

So I'm asking you guys what could be optimized.

Please note I have developed it from scratch and already optimized what I could think of (took 4.5 million cycles before).

BTW, the prime finding algorithm I used is the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Here is the code:

```
            .area PROG (ABS)

        .org 0x100
        .globl program

keyboard    .equ    #0xFF02
screen .equ #0xFF00

limit:  .word 0
limit2000:  .word 0
limitx2:    .word 0
num:    .word 0
numorg: .word 0
countread:  .word 0
cont:   .word 2 ;conter for the load loop
contt:  .word -2 ;used for offset over X pointer
contn:  .word -2000
contnt: .word -2000
primeA: .word 1
primeB: .word 1
primeC: .word 1
square1:    .word 1
square2:    .word 1
squareo:    .word 1
valX:   .word 2000

tmp:    .byte 0
tmp2:   .word 0
tmp3:   .word 0
temp:   .byte 0

program:

ldx #2000
start:
    ldb keyboard
    cmpb    #'\n
    beq end
    cmpb    #0x7F
    beq backspace
    subb    #0x30
    stb tmp
    ldd limit
    lda #10
    mul
    std tmp2
    clra
    ldb tmp
    std tmp3
    ldd tmp2
    addd    tmp3
    std limit
    std ,X++
    ldb countread
    decb
    stb countread
    bra start

backspace:
    lda #8
    sta screen
    sta screen
    lda #' 
    sta screen
    sta screen
    lda #8
    sta screen
    sta screen
    ldb countread
    cmpb    #0
    beq start
    lda #8
    sta screen
    lda #' 
    sta screen
    lda #8
    sta screen
    ldd ,--x
    ldd -2,x
    std limit
    ldb countread
    incb
    stb countread
    bra start

end:
    lda #'\0
    sta ,X
    ldb countread
    cmpb    #0
    beq empty
    andcc   #0b11111011
    ldd limit
    addd    #2000
    std limit2000
    addd    limit2000
    std limitx2
    ldd limit
    ldx #2000
    bra load

empty:
    orcc    #0b00000100
    puls    A,PC

load:
    ldd     cont
    std     ,x++
    addd    #1
    std     cont
    ldd     contn
    subd    #2
    std     contn
    ldd     cont
    cmpd    limit
    blo     load

    ldd     contn
    std     contnt
    ldd     contn
    addd    #2
    bra     findNextPrime

ponerX0:
    ldx     #2000
    bra     ctd3

findNextPrime:
    leax    2,x
    ldx     #2000
    findnp:
        ldd     primeA
        addd    #1
        std     primeA
        ldd     contt
        addd    #2
        std     contt
        ldd     d,x
        cmpd    #0
        beq     findnp
        std     primeA
        bra     deleteMultiples

square:
    ldd     square1
    subd    #1
    std     square1
    ldd     square2
    addd    primeB
    std     square2
    cmpd    limit
    lbhs    printPrimes
    ldd     square1
    cmpd    #1
    bne     square
    bra     ctd2

deleteMultiples:
    std square1
    std square2
    std primeB
    bra square
    ctd2:
        ldd square2
        std primeB
        std primeC
        ldd #0
        std valX
        ldd primeA
        cmpd    #2
        bne ponerX0
        ctd3:
            ldd square2
            lslb
            rola
        ctd:
            leax    2,x
            subd    #2
            std primeC
            ldd valX
            addd    #2
            std valX
            ldd primeC
            cmpd    #4
            bne ctd
        ldd #0
        std ,x
        deleteNum:
            ldd primeA
            lslb
            rola
            delete1Num:
                leax    2,x
                subd    #2
                std primeC
                ldd valX
                addd    #2
                std valX
                ldd primeC
                cmpd    #0
                bne delete1Num
                ldd #0
                std ,x
                ldd valX
                cmpd    limitx2
                lbhs    findNextPrime
                bra deleteNum

printPrimes:
    ldd #-2
    std cont
    ldx #2000
    printPrimesL:
        ldd cont
        addd    #2
        std cont
        ldd d,x
        std num
        cmpd    #0
        bne printString
        ldd cont
        cmpd    limitx2
        blo printPrimesL
        lbra finish

printString: 
    ldd num
    std numorg
    cmpd #500
    lblo less500
    cmpd #700
    blo less700
    cmpd #900
    blo less900
    std temp
    ldb #'9 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #900
    lbra twoDigits

less900:
    cmpd #800
    blo less800
    std temp
    ldb #'8     
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #800
    lbra twoDigits
less800:
    std temp
    ldb #'7     
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #700
    lbra twoDigits
less700:
    cmpd #600
    blo less600
    std temp
    ldb #'6     
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #600
    lbra twoDigits
less600:
    std temp
    ldb #'5     
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #500
    lbra twoDigits
less500:
    cmpd #300
    blo less300
    cmpd #400
    blo less400
    std temp
    ldb #'4 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #400
    lbra twoDigits
less400:
    std temp
    ldb #'3 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #300
    lbra oneDigit
less300:
    cmpd #200
    blo less200
    std temp
    ldb #'2
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #200
    lbra twoDigits
less200:
    cmpd #100
    blo twoDigits
    std temp
    ldb #'1
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #100
twoDigits:
    cmpd #50
    blo less50
    cmpd #70
    blo less70
    cmpd #90
    blo less90
    std temp
    ldb #'9 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #90
    lbra oneDigit
less90:
    cmpd #80
    blo less80
    std temp
    ldb #'8 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #80
    lbra oneDigit
less80:
    std temp
    ldb #'7 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #70
    lbra oneDigit
less70:
    cmpd #60
    blo less60
    std temp
    ldb #'6 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #60
    lbra oneDigit
less60:
    std temp
    ldb #'5
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #50
    lbra oneDigit
less50:
    cmpd #30
    blo less30
    cmpd #40
    blo less40
    std temp
    ldb #'4 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #40
    lbra oneDigit
less40:
    std temp
    ldb #'3 
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #30
    lbra oneDigit
less30:
    cmpd #20
    blo less20
    std temp
    ldb #'2
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #20
    lbra oneDigit
less20:
    cmpd #10
    blo less10
    std temp
    ldb #'1
    stb screen
    ldd temp
    subd #10
    bra oneDigit
less10:
    std temp
    ldd numorg
    cmpd #10
    blo oneDigit
    ldb #'0
    stb screen
    ldd temp
oneDigit:
    addd #48
    stb screen
    ldb #' 
    stb screen
    lbra    printPrimesL


finish: clra
        sta 0xFF01
        .org 0xFFFE
        .word program
```

Comment: If you want fastest, then use this tool to generate a sequence of primes between 1 and 1000, then write another program that loads this sequence into memory, and when given a range simply selects from the pre-generated sequence. Selecting a range from an array should be a few hundred cycles, not millions, and is likely to be the most optimal solution.

Comment: This is for an assignment and we are forbidden from using such methods. No precalculated data.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/213556

Answer (score 1):

As a general observation (my 6809 assembly has become rather rusty after 30 years), you're using only half the register set and doing a lot of loads & stores from and to memory for your scalars. Try figuring out whether you can employ the Y and U registers usefully, especially in your inner loops.

Your `square:` section looks like you're performing a very slow multiplication, which is several sorts of wrong:

- The 6809 is the rare 8-bit microprocessor that has a hardware multiplication instruction.
- Even without a hardware instruction, there are considerably faster ways to multiply.

Comment: You're right about the "square". I don't know why but I thought I would need to calculate squares of numbers larger than 255 so I couldn't use the MUL instruction. But thinking about it the largest square I'm going to need to calculate is 37, so I can use MUL. Thanks for that. I'll look into the rest of what you said later this week (no time right now). Thanks.